# Show that a group is isomorphic to $\Bbb R / \langle 2\pi \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Im new to group theory so I'm not sure how to approach the following exercise.

There is a set: 
$$\Bbb S^1 := \{(\cos\delta,\sin\delta)|\delta\in\Bbb R\} \subseteq \Bbb R^2$$

With operation:
$$(\cos\delta_1,\sin\delta_1)\cdot(\cos\delta_2,\sin\delta_2):= (\cos(\delta_1+\delta_2),\sin(\delta_1+\delta_2))$$

I'm allowed to assume it is a group but I need to show that it is isomorphic to $\Bbb R/\langle 2\pi\rangle$.

How would one approach this question?

Comment: What is an isomorphism? Can you guess a candidate isomorphism? Can you try showing it is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to justify that you can see $\mathbb R/\langle2\pi\rangle$ as $[0,2\pi)$ with cyclic addition. Then you can map directly $t\longmapsto(\cos t,\sin t)$ and show that it is an isomorphism (note that the morphism property was given to you basically by definition).